# Screen streaming between clients who are connected to a django server

Tags: python, django, server, screensharing

I am working on a feature for a project that I'm not sure where to start. I have a django server running on a raspberry pi 3. I want one user (lecturer) to be able to connect to a server, click a screen cast button, and then anyone else (students) connected to the server can watch the screen live.

Does anyone know of any free libraries/services that could help accomplish this? Ideally the users wouldn't have to install anything.